# Converting $.ajax request to use the fetch API with async await (and try catch?)

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, async-await, fetch

I am coming back to web dev after a while. Back in the day, JQuery ajax used used to be the gold standard to make requests on the front end but seems like Javascript's fetch API is the recommended way now.

I am trying to figure out the right way to convert this simple `$.ajax` call to use `fetch` instead. Most of the SO answers show how to use `fetch` with `.then` but not with `async await`.

**This what my AJAX code looks like:**

```
$('.delete-article').on('click', (event) => {
    const target = event.target
    const id = target.attr('data-id')

    $ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: `/article/${id}`,
        success: (response) => {
            alert('Deleted article!')
        },
        error: (e) => {
            alert('Error deleting article!')
        }
    })
})
```

**This is what I have so far in the fetch code:**

```
const deleteArticleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-article')

deleteArticleButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', async(event) => {
        const target = event.target
        const id = target.getAttribute('data-id')
        const res = await fetch(`/articles/${id}`, { method: 'DELETE' })

        if (res) {
            alert('Deleted article!')
        } else {
            alert('Error deleting article!')
        }
    })
})
```

**Some questions I have are:**

1. Does the `await` call to `fetch` need to be wrapped in a `try-catch` block? Is there a possibility of it throwing an error?
2. Is there anything I am missing in my converted code?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the official docs for Fetch API says -

> The fetch specification differs from jQuery.ajax() in three main ways:
>
> 1. The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will
>      resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only
>      reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from
>      completing.
> 2. fetch() won't receive cross-site cookies; you can’t establish a cross site session using fetch. Set-Cookie headers from other sites
>      are silently ignored.
> 3. fetch won’t send cookies, unless you set the credentials init option. (Since Aug 25, 2017. The spec changed the default credentials
>      policy to same-origin. Firefox changed since 61.0b13.)

and for your other question -

> Does the await call to fetch need to be wrapped in a try-catch block?
>   Is there a possibility of it throwing an error?

Yes, you have to put the async/await code in try/catch block to catch the errors and that is one of the basic idea behind using async/await instead of using promise or callbacks is to make code read more synchronous ( If you got what I mean ).

> Is there a possibility of it throwing an error?

Yes, as per the official docs for fetch, it will throw error on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

> Is there anything I am missing in my converted code?

```
const deleteArticleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-article')

deleteArticleButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    try 
     {
        const target = event.target
        const id = target.getAttribute('data-id')
        const res = await fetch(`/articles/${id}`, { method: 'DELETE' })

        if (res) {
            alert('Deleted article!')
        } else {
            alert('Error deleting article!')
        }
     }catch(error){
        // Throw the error if you have parent callee some other method
        // throw(error)
        // Or handle the error here
        alert('API FAILED')
     }

    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. One additional question would be, what is the best way to handle the caught error? Should I just pop an alert for the user saying 'Network error!' since this is the only way that this error is thrown?

Comment: You should be using form validation on the button, on which click event is listening and show inline error message.